# CodeMirror - get linting result from outside of the editor

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, codemirror, lint

I'm using the CodeMirror library which is awesome. The code editor that I'm istantiating is a part of a form and therefore I want to do a basic check with linting to see whether the user's input seems valid. Unless the code is fine, I don't want to process the form.

So the question is: is there a method on the CodeMirror editor instance that would allow me to retrieve the result of linting? I'm looking through the docs and Google but failed to find anything helpful. There's this `performLint` method that is added to the editor, however it does not return the results of linting.

Comment: what is a lint result?

Comment: What I mean is the list of errors/warnings returned from the lint tool defined for an editor. I need it outside of the editor, so that I can find out if the content of the editor is OK

Comment: well you can validate the string `value` of the editor with a custom tool, or look for the markers codemirror uses to indicate those warnings.

Answer (score 11):

There isn't a specific method to get the linting results, but there is a hook provided when you define a `getAnnotations` property in the lint options object.

Here's a basic options object that would trigger linting:

```
var codeMirrorOptions = {
    "lineNumbers": true,
    "indentWithTabs": true,
    "mode": "css",
    "gutters": ['CodeMirror-lint-markers'],
    "lint": true
}
```

You can specify an object (instead of a boolean) as the `lint` property:

```
"lint": {
    "getAnnotations": css_validator,
    "async": true 
}
```

Then, define your own validator function.  This function can just call CodeMirror's bundled validator:

```
     function css_validator(cm, updateLinting, options) {
            // call the built in css linter from addon/lint/css-lint.js
            var errors = CodeMirror.lint.css(cm);

            updateLinting(errors);

        }
```

At this point you've replicated the behavior of lint:true -- but now the `errors` variable contains an array of lint errors.  If `errors.length == 0`, no errors were found.

**Note**: this sample assumes you are linting CSS, but the same would apply for other types.

Comment: Thank you! Extra: when using a custom javascript linting I had to use the following code ```errors = CodeMirror.lint.javascript(cm, options); ``` , otherwise it was throwing error "undefined indent property"

Comment: Hello, I am trying to add the `XML Lint` to my `CodeMirror` application. When XML is syntactically incorrect I would like to show a `X Button` next to the line and display the error message. I tried using `faster-xml-parser` but its not working as I would like. I have posted code, if you get a chance can you please help me out? https://codesandbox.io/s/great-browser-gfzdf?file=/pages/index.vue

Answer (score 7):

The updateLinting function in lint.js passes its annotations (and editor) to the onUpdateLinting option:

```
if (options.onUpdateLinting) options.onUpdateLinting(annotationsNotSorted, annotations, cm);
```

so all you have to do is have your handler as the lint option property:

```
lint: { onUpdateLinting: handleErrors }
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, and it avoids "indirecting" the linting function. Tested and approved. However, as the *onUpdateLinting()* option is not documented, it may disappear in a future release of CodeMirror.

Comment: Also agree that this should be the accepted answer.  This worked great for me, though I'd recommend updating your solution to `lint: { onUpdateLinting: handleErrors, options: {} }` the empty options object is required to prevent lots of console warnings of the form `Bad option: onUpdateLinting` and corresponding bogus lint annotations passed to your callback function.  See: https://github.com/codemirror/CodeMirror/issues/4198

Answer (score 2):

This is a hint for Dezzas Answer:

Write,

```
var errors = CodeMirror.lint.css(cm, options);
```

Otherwise, it will fail.

Comment: Useful and required if used on javascript mode with jshint.js.

Answer (score 2):

@Clem's answer led me in the right direction, though I did run into a few issues.  The first was seeing `Bad option: onUpdateLinting` repeatedly in the console (See this reported [Codemirror issue](https://github.com/codemirror/CodeMirror/issues/4198)).  The second was seeing the annotations array containing null entries sometimes.  Here is my linting configuration passed into Codemirror that solves these issues.  Note that I'm using [react-codemirror2](https://github.com/scniro/react-codemirror2), but the options get passed into Codemirror in the same format.  My component has an optional `onLintingComplete` callback that can be provided by the consuming component and you'll see that callback referenced below where it is passed the array of lint annotations:

```js
  lint: onLintingComplete
    ? {
        onUpdateLinting: (_annotationsNotSorted, annotations) =>
          onLintingComplete(
            // sometimes codemirror includes null annotations in the array, so we want to filter these out
            annotations.filter(annotation => annotation != null)
          ),
        // This empty lint options object is needed here, see: https://github.com/codemirror/CodeMirror/issues/4198
        options: {}, 
      }
    : true,
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. Assigning an empty object to options helped me dealing with that console warning (error) ```Cannot display JSHint error (invalid line 0) {id: "(error)", raw: "Bad {a}option: '{b}'.", code: "E001", evidence: "", line: 0, …}```