# ERROR: Cannot read property 'indent' of undefined (CodeMirror)

Tags: javascript, html, codemirror

I'm trying to make javascript validating codemirror component.

```
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code-js"), {
        lineNumbers: true,
        mode: "javascript",
        gutters: ["CodeMirror-lint-markers"],
        "lint": {
          "getAnnotations": javascript_validator,
          "async": true
        }
      });

      function javascript_validator(cm, updateLinting, options) {
        var errors =  CodeMirror.lint.javascript(cm);
        updateLinting(errors);
               
      }
```

When I'm trying to get anootations from lint, I get these errors... How to define an indent value in my options? I've just started using CodeMirror, so please bear with my ignorance.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indent' of undefined
    at Object.validator [as javascript] (javascript-lint.js:24)
    at javascript_validator (lint.html:76)
    at lintAsync (lint.js:134)
...
```

Comment: Same problem for me :( Did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

In case you never solved this, you need to append the `options` parameter to the function:

```js
var errors =  CodeMirror.lint.javascript(cm, options);
```

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57367043.